# How to get MapType from column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, graphframes

I have working with graphframes and now I am using aggregate Message. The vertex schema is:

```
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- company: string (nullable = true)
 |-- money: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- memoryLearned: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)
```

If I try it:

```
  ...
 def createMessage(memory: org.apache.spark.sql.Column): org.apache.spark.sql.Column = {
    memory + 10
  }

...

val msgToSrc: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = this.createMessage(AM.dst("id"))

val aggregates = gx
        .aggregateMessages
        .sendToSrc(msgToSrc)
        .agg(sum(AM.msg).as("aggMess"))
aggregates.show()
```

It works!, but I need to get keys and values from memoryLearned, so I think it works:

```
...
     def createMessage(memory: org.apache.spark.sql.Column): org.apache.spark.sql.Column = {
        for((k,v) <- memory)
           ...
      }


...

val msgToSrc: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = this.createMessage(AM.dst("memoryLearned"))

val aggregates = gx
        .aggregateMessages
        .sendToSrc(msgToSrc)
        .agg(myUDFA(AM.msg).as("aggMess"))
aggregates.show()
```

I got this error: `"value filter is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Column"`

I tried to search how to cast or get MapType, but i only find functions like explode using the dataframe, but I have not a df, I only have one column...

If I put this: `memory.getItem("aKeyFromMap")` instead of `for(...`, I get the correct value from Map...

Also I have tried to create "aux" DataFrame into `createMessage` (one row and one column) for using df functions, but when I use `.withColumn("newColumn",memory)`, it fails..

I am blocked.. any ideas?

A lot of thanks!!
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate over `MapType` `Column`, and you don't know the key up front, you have to use `UDF` or other operation on the external type (like `map`):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

def createMessage = udf( (memory: Map[String, Integer]) => {
  for( (k,v) <- memory )
  ...
} )
```

You get:

> I got this error: "value filter is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Column"

because for comprehensions are syntactic sugar for `map` / `flatMap` / `filter`.

Comment: Thanks!!!, it works:

  def createMessage = udf((memory: Map[String, Integer]) => {
    var suma = 0
    if (memory != null) {
      for ((k, v) <- memory)
        suma = suma + v
    }
    suma
  })

Comment: Great :) Would you consider [voting up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)? Thanks in advance :)